# Ajax error on datatable initialisation on table within modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I have a modal with a search box within it, which when the search button is hit, has an ajax call which goes to the controller, which then returns a table of results, which is then put into a div.  Like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(viewModel),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.success === true) {
            $("#searchResultsPlaceHolder").show();
            $("#searchResultsPlaceHolder").html(result.view, function() {
                var noOfRows = $('#searchResultsTable tr').length;
                if (noOfRows > 1) {
                    loadSearchDatatable();
                }
            });
        }
    },
    error: function (responseText, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error - ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

All that is fine, and works perfectly up until I try to make it a datatable.  If I take out the lines

```
$("#searchResultsPlaceHolder").html(result.view, function() {
                var noOfRows = $('#searchResultsTable tr').length;
                if (noOfRows > 1) {
                    loadSearchDatatable();
                }
            });
```

and just have

```
$("#searchResultsPlaceHolder").html(result.view)
```

it works fine, it gives me a table with my results.  But as this is in a modal, and the returned results may get quite lengthy, I want to use a datatable to implement pagination and sorting.  But whenever I apply the loadSearchDatatable function to the table after the div is populated with the returned html, I get the error:

*table id=searchResultsTable - Ajax error*

The datatable actually appears, with the sort buttons and paging buttons present, but none of them do anything, and the table is longer than the length I specified (5).  Here is my datatable function:

```
function loadSearchDatatable() {
$('#searchResultsTable').dataTable({
        ajax: "data.json",
        "bLengthChange": false,
        'iDisplayLength': 5,
        "bSort": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bFilter": false,
        "sDom": 'ft<"bottom"ilp>',
        "bDestroy": false,
        "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]]
    });
};
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below instead:

```
$("#searchResultsPlaceHolder").html(result.view);

var noOfRows = $('#searchResultsTable tr').length;
if (noOfRows > 1) {
   loadSearchDatatable();
}
```

Also remove `ajax: "data.json",` in your function `loadSearchDatatable()`.